# How to call qt mousepressevent explicitly?

Tags: qt

I have a button class where i have used mouse press and release event. Suppose i want when i press a button another child window should open and until that child 
window is opened the button should be pressed state. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the mouse press/release events to detect actions on your buttons unless you have very specific needs, and don't care at all about keyboard actions and shortcuts. Use the `clicked()` signal.

To make your button stay depressed after a click, you should put your [`QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qpushbutton.html) to toggle button mode by calling `setCheckable(true)` when you construct it.

It will emit the `clicked()` signal when you press it like usual, but will stay in depressed state until either you click on it again, or you call `setChecked(false);` on it.

So, when you dismiss the popup window, simply uncheck the toggle button. (Or have the second click on that button, that will uncheck it, also dismiss the popup.)

Note: calling `setChecked(bool)` never triggers the `clicked()` signal. But it triggers the `toggled(bool)` if you need that.

Comment: Actually i am repainting image in each mouse hovered, press, released case.Your concept is somewhat ok but in this case how you will deal with hovered case? how i will know mouse painter entered my widget?